# Sharing constructor parameters with closure

Tags: javascript, closures

I'm trying to understand why one of these versions works and the other does not.  Why is it illegal to make the `getConfigFails` assignment?

```
var MyClass = (function(){
    var _config;
    function MyClass(config){
        _config = config;
    }
    MyClass.prototype.getConfigWorks = function(){
        _config.getConfigWorks();
    }
    //Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getConfigFails' of undefined
    MyClass.prototype.getConfigFails = _config.getConfigFails;
    return MyClass;
})();
var myClass = new MyClass({
    getConfigWorks:function(){
        console.log('no errors here');
    },
    getConfigFails: function(){ console.log('fail')}
});

console.log(myClass);
```

Comment: Set a breakpoint at `MyClass.prototype.getConfigFails = _config.getConfigFails;` and inspect the value of `_config`.

Comment: and then the light bulb came on.  The closure executes immediately and the real constructor hasn't been called yet, so it's parameters are undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first note that your constructor is not the `(function(){})()` function but rather the `function MyClass(){}` function. The outer self-calling function is there merely to create a closure to make `_config` private.

Knowing this. It is obvious that the code should also work if we don't care if `_config` is private should it not? That is, the logic is the same if `_config` is a global variable.

So, if we can allow `_config` to be global, you code is exactly the same as this:

```
var _config;
function InnerClass(config){
    _config = config;
}
InnerClass.prototype.getConfigWorks = function(){
    _config.getConfigWorks();
}
//Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getConfigFails' of undefined
InnerClass.prototype.getConfigFails = _config.getConfigFails;

var MyClass = InnerClass;

var myClass = new MyClass({
    getConfigWorks:function(){
        console.log('no errors here');
    },
    getConfigFails: function(){ console.log('fail')}
});

console.log(myClass);
```

Written like this. It is obvious why `_config.getConfigFails` is undefined. It's because you haven't assigned anything to it.

It's important to remember, that calling `new MyClass()` merely calls the constructor, not any code surrounding it. Therefore, if you re-wrap the above code in an IIFE the logic doesn't change and only the constructor is called, not the IIFE.

Comment: The work-around should be obvious - attach those functions directly to `this` instead of using `.prototype`. But if it's not clear just mention it in a comment and I can add the work-around in the answer itself

Comment: this was an exercise in specifically trying to use the prototype, that's what I was trying to avoid, adding a different copy of the function for each object.

Comment: I didn't put everything together.  I knew the IIFE wasn't the constructor, but, it does execute immediately and make an assignment to something that is undefined! :)

Comment: @wootscootinboogie: Yep. That's the "immediate" in **I**IFE :D